# Shiny bsModal: Possible to remove the x close button in title?

Tags: shiny, shinybs

I have my Shiny `bsModal` setup as so:

```
# ui.R
bsModal("test_events_modal", htmlOutput("modal_title"), trigger='dummy', size = "large",
  div(dataTableOutput("current_test_events_dt"), style = "font-size:90%;width:95%")
)

# server.R
modal_title = glue('EVENT HISTORY: {selected_flow_context}') 
output$modal_title <- renderUI({ span(tagList(icon("timeline"), modal_title)) })
toggleModal(session, 'test_events_modal', toggle = "toggle")
```

This produces:

[image]

I would like the title text to be left aligned and would like to remove the annoying and redundant 'x' widget as the `bsModal` object has a close button.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [htmltools::tagQuery](https://rstudio.github.io/htmltools/articles/tagQuery.html) to achive this.

As your code isn't reproducible I've adapted [this example](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Modals.html):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(htmltools)

shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          sliderInput("bins",
                      "Number of bins:",
                      min = 1,
                      max = 50,
                      value = 30),
          actionButton("tabBut", "View Table")
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("distPlot"),
          tagQuery(bsModal("modalExample", "Data Table", "tabBut", size = "large",
                           dataTableOutput("distTable")))$find("button")$addAttrs("style" = "display:none;")$allTags()
        )
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        
        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
        
      })
      
      output$distTable <- renderDataTable({
        
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        
        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        tab <- hist(x, breaks = bins, plot = FALSE)
        tab$breaks <- sapply(seq(length(tab$breaks) - 1), function(i) {
          paste0(signif(tab$breaks[i], 3), "-", signif(tab$breaks[i+1], 3))
        })
        tab <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, tab))
        colnames(tab) <- c("Bins", "Counts", "Density")
        return(tab[, 1:3])
        
      }, options = list(pageLength=10))
      
    }
)
```

Comment: The `tagQuery` did remove the little x button but also removed the Close button.  I will dig into the API but wondered if you had a way to be a bit more specific?